# How to Use ViewModelProvider to get my custom ViewModel which extends AndroidViewModel?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a custom ViewModel that extends AndroidViewModel. In the constructor of my custom ViewModel, I'm passing the Application.

In the Main Activity, I tried getting the ViewModel using

```
CustomViewModel customViewModel = ViewModelProviders.to(this)...
```

But it says that it's a deprecated method.
So I wanted to use ViewModelProvider, but I saw that it takes no arguments.

How am I to pass the Application then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    ViewModelProviders.of(this)[CustomViewModel::class.java]
```

you can use `of` method instead of `to`. there is one other thing though you cant create ViewModel for your application class like that. `of` method only takes Activity and Fragment classes.

Comment: I don't have 'ViewModelProviders' method, must be because I don't have the old dependencies. How can I do it with 'ViewModelProvider'?

Comment: android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1 add this dependancy and it will appear